# Using the word ping

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Is it correct to say:

> I will **ping** you on WhatsApp.

or it's better to say:

> I will message you on WhatsApp.

I am not sure if ping has become a synonym for message.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. You must tell us how you tried to answer yourself this question but couldn't. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ping says:

> [ T ] informal
> to send an email or text message:
> Ping me an email.

So yes, you can use ping as a synonym for message in an informal situation.

Personally I would only use it when talking about a specifically short message. Something like "you ready to go?" or "Are you here?".

Given how whatsapp is typically used that certainly fits.